# How to avoid the automatic loading of all files in order to separate loading for some routes(e.g. /admin)?

Tags: templates, meteor, iron-router

Meteor concatenates, minifies and compiles all html, css and javascript  and sends them all to the client. But as I noticed, it's not useful for some cases.

For example, for most users we have app which works on myapp.com and another big part of app - admin dashboard works on myapp.com/admin. The size of admin part is compatible to the size of a main app part, but it's used only by hundreds of users or so. As a result most of the users load 2x size on client, half of which is useless and can't be used.

Does Meteor have solutions of this problem or maybe someone can suggest any hacks to solve it?

Comment: Currently, there is no way to achieve this. Meteor will minifies everything as a single file and serve it to the client.Alternatively you can create two different meteor apps with the same mongodb database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you made your whole /admin/ section a separate package you could deploy two builds, with and without, and then route any clicks on "/admin/" URLs to "admin.APP.com/admin". both apps would of course need to talk to the same database.

Some people are using nginx proxy to decide what to serve, but this is not so much based on URLs as on some property of the userAgent, eg for mobile devices. this is nicer than having separate subdomains. the user doesn't see "admin.APP.com", the different backends are masked from them. But, you may not care so much about that. Having admin.* be explicit is a good thing.